# "Разухабистый": при чем тут ухабы?

Tags: этимология

Лихой, удалой — обычно в ироничном значении "разухабистый". А интересно было бы узнать происхождение слова. При чем тут ухабы?

Answer (score 3):

Ухабистый-бойкий, разбитной, неприличный, бессовестный, охальный- по Фасмеру,происходит от прил. ухабистый и сущ. ухаб, далее из формы, родств. русск. диалектному  ха́бить "портить", похабить, похабный.

Так что ухаб - битость дороги,выбоина, а ухабистый человек или поступок - разБИТной - однокоренное слово получается с переносным значением - тоже битый, испорченный.

Answer (score 2):

ЗНАЧЕНИЕ.
Из Ожегова: РАЗУХАБИСТЫЙ, (прост.).  1.  Молодцеватый,  задорный. Разухабистая песня. 2. Слишком  вольный, развязный (неодобр.).  Разухабистые манеры.

ОБРАЗОВАНИЕ.
Ухаб - разухабистый, сравнить: лапа - разлапистый, приставка РАЗ имеет значение "в разные стороны" и дополнительно усиливает признак.

ПРОИСХОЖДЕНИЕ.
Ухаб - от слова "хабить" - портить, получаем речь с ухабами во все стороны, то  есть "испорченную" относительно общепринятой. "Испорченность" здесь мыслится самая разнообразная: выражения как бойкие, задорные, так и просто неприличные. Отсюда два значения слова.

Переносное значение образуется следующим образом: ухаб, неровность на дороге - неровность в обобщенном значении.   "Разухабистой езды" в прямом значении у нас нет: если мы просто едем по дороге с ухабами, то такое движение нельзя назвать разухабистым. Слово "разухабистый" характеризует любое действие как действие "с ухабами", а далее оно уже конкретизируется по темам.Разухабистая езда, наверное, тоже существует, но это, скорее, рискованная езда по обычной дороге.

Comment: >"Разухабистой езды" в прямом значении у нас нет: если мы просто едем по дороге с ухабами, то такое движение нельзя назвать разухабистым.

Можно или нельзя — это определяется сознательным выбором скорости и допфичами: бубенцами, колокольчиками, той старинною семиструнною... по современной бум-бум-боксовой технологии.

Comment: София, изменение содержания своего ответа по прочтении ответов других форумцев допускает определённого термина. Согласны?

----------------------------------------------- 

После десяти первых знаков в комментарии открывается возможность употребления ещё 590 знаков.

Comment: Пробую научиться комментировать - может быть, получится. Но вот что интересно: эта система раньше вела себя по-другому и, кажется,  говорила мне "нужно 10 знаков". Я решила, что пока не будет десяти знаков, я комментировать не могу.

Comment: Так  и  есть.  Коммент  из  восьми  знаков  я  отрпавить  не  смог.

Answer (score 1):

> **luke**: При чем тут ухабы?

Ухабы (и колдобины тоже) на дороге здесь при том, что служат *причиной* порождения разухабистых *следствий*: "удобства" самой езды по такой дороге и последующего состояния транспортного средства. Отсюда и смысл в переносном значении применительно к  характеристике поведения, речи и возможного прочего.

Comment: Ухаб  это  порча.  Ухаб  на  дороге  -  это  то,  что   её  портит:  выбоина  или  что  другое.  Разухабистый,  как  и  похабный   тоже   порченый,   только  в  другом   смысле,   нравственном.   Общее  -  порча.

Answer (score 1):

Раз/ухабистый - готовый к любой неожиданности, ловкий и малопредсказуемый человек.  Куда его вывернет нелегкая - одному богу известно. Разухабистая песня - она и рассмешит, и покраснеть заставит, и в дрожь бросит...

> С. А. Есенин. Яр (1915) **Ухабистый мужик** размахнулся, и переломившийся о голову сотского кол окунулся расщепленным концом в красную, как воронок, кровь.

Я хочу обратить внимание форумчан на старинное слово *ухабничий/ухабничей*, которое означало :

> **Ухабничий** , придворный служитель, который
> стоял на запятках или отводах саней, оберегая
> их от опрокидки. (Даль)

"Стоять на ухабах" было достаточно почетной должностью, ведь *ухабничий* своей ловкостью и недюжинной сноровкой мог реально спасти жизнь высокопоставленным "пассажирам".
Однако и унизить можно было **камер-юнкера** подобной службой :

> Как за церковью, за немецкою,
> Добрый молодец богу молится:
> - Как не дай, боже, хорошу жену, -
> Хорошу жену в честной пир зовут,
> Меня, молодца, не примолвили,
> **Молоду жену - в новы саночки,
>
> Меня, молодца, - на запяточки.**
> Молоду жену - на широкий двор,
> Меня, молодца, - за воротички.
> (Пушкин, авторские стихи, стилизованные под народную песню)
> http://www.znanie-sila.ru/golden/issue2print_83.html

Ухабистым-разухабистым придворным поэтом, которому нипочем любые удары и насмешки, Пушкин стать не смог.

Соблазны большого города :

> А. И. Левитов. Московские «комнаты снебилью» (1863)
> ... за обедом вместо угрюмых, изработавшихся лиц своих семейских мужиков **она видит разухабистых Захаров в красных рубахах**, с блестящими серьгами в левых ушах, ― веселых Захаров, непременно довольных и собою, и хозяйскою кашей, с глазами, лукаво прищуренными на новую стряпуху, с бойкой, вырывающей из компании волны хохота, поговоркой...